# Is this a valid .h C header file that can be used for Java Native Interface JNI?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to understand if the file that was provided to me is something I can use Jave Native Interface with, where I can write a Java class and create `native` abstract methods corresponding to C functions in the `.h` header file.

So, what I have now is a `.ec` file and `.h` file. Both were provided to me.
I was asked to try to use JNI to invoke functions from `.ec` file.

However, I noticed that some common JNI keywords like `JNIEXPORT`, `JNICALL`, `JNIEnv*`, `jobject` are NOT present in either `.ec` or `.h` files that was given to me.

The `.h` file looks like this :

```
#ifndef _BITMAP_H
#define _BITMAP_H 1

struct BITMAP
{
    char *buffer;   // buffer 
    int   ax;       // width
    int   ay;       // height
    int   size;     // buffer size
};
struct BITMAP *create(int ax, int ay);
void close( struct BITMAP *pbmp );
void drawLn( struct BITMAP *pbmp, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 );
void drawTxt(struct BITMAP *pbmp, char *szText, int x, int y );
void setPxl( struct BITMAP *pbmp, int x, int y );
#endif
```

Is this a valid file to use JNI with?
I'm a total beginner with JNI but I suspect, and it looks like JNI is not applicable to this kind of file definition.

Are there other Java technology or library to invoke these methods from `.ec` file?

I'd appreciate any comment or explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you might be able to use JNA but JNI requires dedicated code, it can't just use normal C functions

Comment: @AlanBirtles, thanks for your comment about JNA. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO its not a valid header file. You don't look at java native code and try to create a header file by hand instead you let javac generate the header file for you using the -h option

> -h directory Specifies where to place generated native header files.
>
> When you specify this option, a native header file is generated for
> each class that contains native methods or that has one or more
> constants annotated with the java.lang.annotation.Native annotation.
> If the class is part of a package, then the compiler puts the native
> header file in a subdirectory that reflects the module name (if
> appropriate) and package name. The directory, and any necessary
> subdirectories, will be created if they do not already exist.

Javac will compile class files containing native methods and will output the header files for you. Documentation [here](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/panama/docs/specs/man/javac.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sync it. Now I don't have to waste effort to try to run that code. I am now reading through the JNA that AlanBirtles suggested in comment.